# Scaldi: couldn't find bindings defined in typesafe config

Tags: typesafe-config, scaldi

Here is the issue. Let assume I have two mutable modules:

```
class DbModule extends Module {   bind[JdbcBackend#Database] toProvider
    inject[JdbcDriver].backend.Database.forURL(
      inject[String]("db.url"),
      inject[String]("db.username"),
      inject[String]("db.password"), null,
      inject[String]("db.driver")
    ) }
```

and here is the corresponding config:

resources/application.conf:

```
db {  url="postgres url"  username="db_user"  password="db_password"  driver="cc"  }
```

Somewhere in the code I do:

```
implicit val inj = TypesafeConfigInjector() :: new AppModule
```

However this injector gives the following exception:

```
caldi.InjectException: No binding found with following identifiers:  
* TypeTagIdentifier(String)   * StringIdentifier(db.url)
```

Answer (score 1):

The order in Scaldi is important: the binding is resolved from left to right.

The `::` operator, [as stated in the docs](http://scaldi.org/learn/#injector-composition), composes two injectors by inverting the operands. Thus, in your case, `AppModule` is resolved first, hence it cannot find the config params injected.

To solve your problem, use the `++` operator to keep your injectors in order.

I hope this is helpful.